# How do I select a file in PHP randomly from directory?

Tags: php, glob

I have to randomly select a file from a directory in PHP, let's say there are three files let's say index.php , a.php and b.php. How do I make sure that I don't pick up file index.php but pick up other files randomly.
I have following code up to this point

```
$dir = 'uploads';
$files = glob($dir . '/*.php');
$file = array_rand($files);
echo $files[$file];
```

Comment: ...by not having index.php in your directory that holds random files that shouldn't give back index.php... surely?

Comment: Add an if to check whether  `$files[$file]` doesn't equal to _index.php_

Comment: I can't move index.php

Comment: should the check be `$dir.index.php` == $files[$file]` or just `index.php` == $files[$file]`

Comment: Had forgotten a not :D, I edited my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just build an array to exclude and use `array_diff()`:

```
$exclude = array("$dir/index.php");
$files = array_diff(glob("$dir/*.php"), $exclude);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$dir = 'uploads';
$files = glob($dir . '/*.php');
while (in_array($file = array_rand($files),array('index.php')));
echo $files[$file];
```

You can exclude other filenames in that array containg 'index.php'.

It only works when there are more files than 'index.php' in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

My setup for getting random files, maybe you just have to add the file extension,.. but this works for sure.

I don't like [array_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) because it will duplicate the array, it is also using a lot of CPU and RAM.

I came up with this result.

```
<?php
$handle = opendir('yourdirname');
$entries = [];
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
  if($entry == 'index.php'){
    // Sorry now allowed to read this one...
  }else{
    $entries[] = $entry;
  }
}

// Echo a random item from our items in our folder.
echo getrandomelement($entries);


// Not using array_rand because to much CPU power got used.
function getrandomelement($array) {
    $pos=rand(0,sizeof($array)-1);
      $res=$array[$pos];
      if (is_array($res)) return getrandomelement($res);
        else return $res;
}
```